# How to export the docker variables?

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

I'm new to docker.My Operating system is Mac OS.
I follow the step from docker website,

1. Download the boot2docker and install it.
2. run the boot2docker
3. `$ boot2docker init`
4. `$ boot2docker start`
5. `$ docker run hello-world`

the result is that :

```
bash-3.2$ docker run hello-world
```

> An error occurred trying to connect: Post https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.19/containers/create: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, 10.0.2.15, not 192.168.59.103

then i do

`$ boot2docker shellinit` to display the environment variables

`bash-3.2$ boot2docker shellinit`

> Writing /Users/wangyao/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/ca.pem
>
> Writing /Users/wangyao/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/cert.pem
>
> Writing /Users/wangyao/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm/key.pem
>
> Your environment variables are already set correctly.

maybe I think it makes error by not configuring the variables, So I do this

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.59.103:2376
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/wangyao/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

then I `$ boot2docker shellinit`, and the result is no different,

Please tell me how to resolve it

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question to me.

Comment: oh , I was edite my question  just now  ,  please look it again, Thanks

Comment: This is a system configuration issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: You should do `$(boot2docker shellinit)` not just `boot2docker shellinit`. I don't think that's the issue though...

Answer (score 1):

I explained how to use [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/) instead of boot2docker, if you're interested: [Can't run docker on os X with boot2docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157999/cant-run-docker-on-os-x-with-boot2docker/31167685#31167685).

Because I think Boot2Docker won't be the recommended way of using Docker (on Windows/OS X) any longer soon.

TL;DR

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
docker run hello-world
```