# Can't run docker on os X with boot2docker

Tags: macos, docker, boot2docker

I've tried to remove docker with this [manual](http://therealmarv.com/blog/how-to-fully-uninstall-the-offical-docker-os-x-installation/).

And I removed virtualbox. And then tried to install boot2docker.

After boot2docker init etc (by the manual on docker site)

> docker run helloworld

gives me this error

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this
>   host?

```
boot2docker status
running

docker version
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Droppy what is the proper stackexchange site for that in your opinion?

Comment: No idea, but it's not here.

Comment: @Droppy, there lots of questions that are not about programming on SO. E.g. about gradle which a build tool, not a language. Docker is used by programmers in exactly the same way as gradle.

Comment: @Opal You should vote to close them then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `boot2docker up` then `docker run helloworld`.

Comment: if that's the same as boot2docker start, then I've already done that. I've read the manual of course.

Comment: Strange. Are you running boot2docker and image as the same user? Try `boot2docker status` before running `docker run <image>`. What's the output?

Comment: Strange indeed. Yes, I'm running boot2docker and image as the same user. There is a issue https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/issues/112

Comment: @user1685095 no idea what the problem may be, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Boot2docker is not the recommended way of using Docker (on Windows/OS X) anymore (IMHO).

See [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/) instead (which can use the "boot2docker iso" internally, but not only).

You may also want to import your existing boot2docker environment (to keep your built images, etc.), it's [possible too](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/experimental/b2d_migration.md).

Then using Docker Machine, you can create a working Docker environment with the following commands:

On OS X (or an OS which supports `eval` and `export` commands), if you have the `Docker CLI` installed:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
eval "$(docker-machine env dev)"
docker run hello-world
```

OR

On any OS, if you have **not** the `Docker CLI` installed:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
docker-machine ssh dev
docker run hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the daemon is not running?

```
Damiens-MacBook-Air:tmp damien$ docker version
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is 'docker -d' running on this host?
```

... check if the daemon is running :

```
Damiens-MacBook-Air:tmp damien$ boot2docker ssh sudo /etc/init.d/docker status
Docker daemon is not running
error in run: exit status 1
```

then start it :

```
Damiens-MacBook-Air:tmp damien$ boot2docker ssh sudo /etc/init.d/docker start
Need TLS certs for boot2docker,127.0.0.1,10.0.2.15,192.168.59.103
-------------------
```

and now you should be able to connect.

```
Damiens-MacBook-Air:tmp damien$ docker version
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
Server version: 1.7.0
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 0baf609
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```